# What does $$[QT_HOST_DATA/get] do in a Qt Feature configuration (.prf) file?

Tags: qt, configuration, qmake

Where is the following syntax used in a feature configuration (`.prf`) file? defined:

```
$$[QT_HOST_DATA/get]
```

I know `$$[ ... ]` is to access QMake properties as explained in the Qt doc, but where is the /get part of the notation in `$$[QT_HOST_DATA/get]` clarified? And what does it precisely do?

Also, inside a Qt `.conf` file, what is the difference between `include` (for other `.conf` files) and load() (for `.prf` files)?

If `include(some.conf)` merely consists in the contents of `some.conf` to be literally pasted into the including `.conf` file, what does `load()` do exactly?

I have found no info about the structure of `.prf` files.
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html says that you can create `.prf` files, but says nothing about how these files are processed or should be structured?

Thanks for any clarifications you can provide!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> where is the /get part of the notation in $$[QT_HOST_DATA/get] clarified? And what does it precisely do?

Nowhere, except qmake source code. It looks like all qmake properties may have upto four special "subproperies": `xxx/dev xxx/src xxx/raw xxx/get`. However, what are they used for is a mystery. Executing `qmake -query QT_HOST_DATA/get` produces (on my machine) just the same value as plain `$$[QT_HOST_DATA]`.

> I have found no info about the structure of .prf files.

Basically, .prf is just "system include file". There are two points, though:

1. All .prf files reside in a known location(s) pointed by `QMAKEFEATURES` variable.

BTW. `QMAKEFEATURES` is a sort of "protected variable". I managed to change it only with the help of (another undocumented) `cache()` function:

```
QMAKEFEATURES *= mydir # '*=' because of 3 passes under Windows
# 'transient' prevents creation file on disk
# only 'super' seems to work OK; no idea what's wrong with 'stash' or 'cache'
cache(QMAKEFEATURES, set transient super) 
# now I can load .prf from <mydir> too...
```

2. Prf can be implicitly loaded by mentioning it in `CONFIG` variable. For example, `CONFIG += qt` (which is the default, btw.) results in include of `<SomePrefix>/share/qt5/mkspecs/features/qt.prf` Note that this takes place after the whole .pro was processed, so .prf file can be used to post-process user options.

> what does load() do exactly?

It's just the version of `include()` designed specially for .prf. All it does, it simply includes .prf file. But, unlike `CONFIG += xxx`, it does this immediately, and, unlike plain `include()`, you shouldn't specify path and extension.